# iBeacon protocol - distance clarification

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

Well started of learning iBeacon protocol, just one quick query, dose this protocol specify only 3 levels of distance detection or it can be any thing from 0 - 70 mtrs.

I mean there are 3 levels far, near , immediate  are their values protocol driven or we can set them.

I am looking for something around 4 -7 meters mark and as far as i know the above values are 1.5,10 & 70

Answer (score 0):

You can get finer distance *estimates* by accessing the `CLBeacon` `accuracy` property.  It gives you a floating point number in meters.

While there is much more precision on this field, you should understand that these distance estimates are based on radio signal strength, which is inherently noisy.  Under ideal conditions, you can expect to get estimates of 0.5-2 meters when you are 1 meter away.  The further you go away the more fluctuation and inaccuracy there is on these measurements.

Read more here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html